# Spring Data dto projection method

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, dto

I have a query in the below which is complicated but i need to project this DeploymentDto which method i can use for projection? This query is in interface class which extends JpaRepository. Later in another class i need to use resulting list in my code.

Basically i need to map my native query into dto, so for query like mine how can i do it? I did research but JPQL query for example uses simple native queries.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT a.name, a.created_at, a.updated_at, d.version, a.image, d.id, d.app_id\n" +
            "FROM applications a\n" +
            "LEFT JOIN deployments d ON d.app_id = a.id\n" +
            "WHERE d.app_id IS NULL\n" +
            "union\n" +
            "select a.name, d.created_at, d.updated_at, d.version, a.image, d.id, d.app_id from applications a\n" +
            "inner join deployments d on d.app_id = a.id\n" +
            "where d.updated_at = (\n" +
            "select max(d1.updated_at) from deployments d1 where d1.app_id = a.id)\n" +
            "ORDER BY name",  nativeQuery = true)
    List<Deployment> findLatestDeployments();
```

I cannot use directly it like List  findLatestDeployments(); It gave an error like this:

```
{"timestamp":1595277133888,"message":"No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.gg.applications.model.DeploymentDto]"
```

Comment: The query will be executed when the method is invoked (assuming everything is wired up correctly) so not sure what  _which method i can use for projection_ means.

Comment: I need to use dto of deployment in my project instead of deployment itself. when i try to convert last part into List<DeploymentDto> findLatestDeployments(); it gives an error so i need to map result directly into DTO but JPQL query for example does not work on me because of my query is complex and i dont know how to do it

Comment: i updated my question, i hope i'm clear :(

Answer (score 1):

If your DTO is a class you need to use `@SqlResultSetMapping`. I would however recommend to [make your DTO a Interface and use this as a projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces).

```
interface Deployment{
  public String name();
  public LocalDateTime created_at();
  public LocalDateTime updated_at();
  public long version();
  public byte[] image();
  public Long id();
  public Long app_id();
}
```

Comment: yes it's class so my data is also big and if i want to iterate over after i constructed deployment list, will it be fast to work on with? I'm developing a project, so it has to be as fast as possible

Comment: Performance wise there will be no difference between a class and an interface projection. Your SQL query will be crucial for performance.

Comment: one more question, which one should i use constructor result mapping or entity result mapping. idk the difference between them

Comment: Honestly i didnt know entity result mapping. When i decide to use a projection then i want the data read only, so constructor result is sufficent.

Comment: i have already DeploymentDto class and when i put @SqlResultSetMapping there it gives an error. I googled it and put Entity tag but it still gives an error. "SqlResultSetMapping' not applicable to field". Class also got Data Getter Setter AllArgsConstructor NoArgsConstructor Builder tags too